# What is feature ID for Feature "Open Document in default application" SP 2010

Tags: 2010, powershell, feature

What is feature ID of Feature "Open Document in default application" in SharePoint 2010 environment?

Comment: Have you tried google? http://lmgtfy.com/?q=sharepoint+2010+feature+ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily find this information using PowerShell `Get-SPFeature` cmdlet

```
Get-SPFeature -Limit All | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "*open*" }
```

Feature id is `8a4b8de2-6fd8-41e9-923c-c7c3c00f8295`

You can find this from [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsnoiwb/archive/2010/01/07/features-and-their-guid-s-in-sp2010.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

here we go:

```
Display Name: OpenInClient  
Title:  Open documents in client applications   
GUID:8a4b8de2-6fd8-41e9-923c-c7c3c00f8295
```

You can run the following the command to get all features:

```
Get-SPFeature | select ID, DisplayName, Scope
```

[SharePoint 2010 : List of Features "ID, DisplayName and Scopes"](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7695.sharepoint-2010-list-of-features-id-displayname-and-scopes.aspx)